# Firebase Cloud Functions TS - Unresolved functions/variables/methods

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, webstorm, firebase-admin

I use the IDE WebStorm, and I'm having some difficulties coding the cloud functions. It looks like WebStorm doesn't recognize some methods/ functions/variables of firebase.

Example:

[image]

The dark red color means that it couldn't resolve the property.
As you can see, it doesn't recognize `db.settings`, `snapshot.data()`, `db.doc()` and `snapshot.id`.

My package.json (auto-generated, haven't touched anything):

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json",
    "build": "tsc",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "~6.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "tslint": "~5.8.0",
    "typescript": "~2.8.3"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

What I tried so far with no success:

- Invalidate and Restart
- Reinstall node_modules
- Cancel exclusion of the package `@google-cloud`
- delete `functions` and `firebase init functions` - Worked for a moment and then it failed to locate the source.
- Tried to un-exclude `node_modules` just for the sake of it.

Unexcluded packages:

- @google-cloud
- @types (+ @types/*)
- firebase-admin
- firebase-functions
- tslint
- typescript

PS - I don't know if it has to do with the parent folder, but I'm using Ionic 4 in this project, while in another project I use only Angular and it behaves well (both functions folders has the exact same settings).

#### Update 1 - I tried to run this project both on PC and MacOS (different devices) and it happens in both of them. This issue doesn't happen on different projects.

Comment: If everything builds ok with `npm run build`, then the problem lies within webstorm.

Comment: it outputs an error. But it something regarding the parent directory (the app itself), But actually, there's no error at all. I had to change the build script to `tsc --skipLibCheck`.

Comment: I tested with "firebase init" function only. with VS code all good and your package.json has no problem. FYI, firebase-admin module refers @google-cloud/firestore types. I presume your webstorm does not parse properly.

Comment: @JohnCho I think the problem has to do with the parent directory and not with the functions folder, since I have the exact same folder in a different app and Webstorm parses it properly

Comment: @Eliya Cohen easier debug way is from simple code. I just confirmed nothing wrong with your package.json file. As you mentioned, webstorm works with others project. Then your code are not compatible with webstorm. Can you provide source code?

Comment: I would love to share that source code, but it's signed under NDA. Anyway, I guess I won't find an answer here since I can't elaborate enough to figure out it doesn't work. What I can tell you - the parent folder is ionic 4 project.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that FireStore functions are actually declared in `@google-cloud/firestore` plugin that is installed as a dependency of `firebase-admin` but not listed in your project `package.json`. And WebStorm auto-excludes all indirect dependencies from indexing for better performance, so functions definitions are not available to code analyser. To work out the issue, right-click `node_modules/@google-cloud` folder in your **Project** tool window and shooe **Mark directory as/Not excluded**. This should solve the issue:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Plus, try to hover on settings. Will it show you its source too?

Comment: yes - see updated answer. please try invalidating caches after un-excluding the folder

Comment: Still, no luck. I have another project with the same dependencies and it works there. I tried to compare the node_modules and it looks the same.